# Sitemap XML URL is not updating in SXA

Tags: sxa

We have been using Sitecore with SXA. Website is hosted in the Azure environment and we have a Traffic Manager which points to 2 CD URLs. Recently we moved to live environment since my project is kind of migration. We switched our website to old website name but sitemap URL are still pointing to Traffic Manager URL.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the sitemap uses the Host Name defined in the Basic section in the Site Grouping Site Settings item of your site to connect to site and generate sitemap xml.

You can find it through Content Editor by navigating to /sitecore/content/....[sxa site]/Settings/Site Grouping/[sxa site]:

[image]

"Host Name" or "Target Host Name" are still pointing new website, just change it and you should be fine.

More information about sitemap in SXA [can be found here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/configuring/configure_a_sitemap).

You can also check setup of your sites through [SXA Site Manager](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/setting_up/manage_multiple_sites_with_the_sxa_site_manager).

Comment: Target hostname resolves the issue :)